# Difference between social tag and hashtag?

Tags: google-search, tags

[Official Google Search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) page has entries:

> `@`   Find social tags
>           Example: `@agoogler`
>
> `#`   Find popular hashtags for trending topics
>           Example: `#throwbackthursday`

What is the difference between *social tags* and *hashtags*?

How should I structure page and URL in order to page be recognized having *social tag* and *hashtag*?

Answer (score 5):

When you use @, you are directing what you are writing to a person or thing.

When you use #, you are directing what you are writing to a topic.

Many people get this wrong, including one specific client of mine who, every year, I have to jump on them for using the @ tag for everything they write.

If you want to speak to everyone that likes butterflies, it's #butterflies, otherwise you are speaking to one thing, likely socially to a person,  @butterflies.

Comment: Thanks for answer! So social/hash tags are just plain prefixed text and do not require special HTML markup? As I start to understand that texts are filled in social media forms and so may not contain HTML, but usually sites wraps tags with link when processing markup.

Comment: Who makes these "rules"?   That distinction is so technical that I can't imagine my grandmother learning it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I DO! And if you don't like it .... :) Everything I know about it I learned from Twitter. Whether they are the originator of it, I don't know. btw, notice the @ in this comment.

Comment: I would much rather be able to say "Rob: here is what I think of that" than have to use the `@` in front of your name.    Actually, either way should probably work.   Also bare names without any symbol.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Then how do you identify a bare name you are addressing and trying to message? Then every name you use gets a message. And how do you identify what is a name and what isn't?

Comment: I use the feature because the SE system is specially coded to send a message to the person if you do so.   The hash sign just baffles me.   I see no advantage to using them.  It just makes posts less readable.  #confused

Comment: Because of the context?   If I mention AtulBhatS shouldn't it send a message with the `@` in this context.

Comment: If I want to send a message to ChicagoFringe organizers, but it's not relevant to those going to ChicagoFringe, then I can use @. If I want to tell people where to buy tickets to "40 Minutes to Howard", I certainly don't need to tell the @ChicagoFringe people that, so, #ChicagoFringe and everyone sees it.

Comment: "everyone sees it"  is the part I've never understood.  How do they see it?   Is there something that notifies them?  Are there subscriptions to topics?   I've never found anything like that.

Comment: On Twitter, at least, I get a notification if someone @'s me. If you did #Rob, it would wind up in a category that you need to be following to get a notification though I don't know if you get one at all. I don't want to give an impression that I'm the social go-to guy. I just know what I need to get by and don't really use it much myself.

Answer (score 2):

@ refers to users or accounts. Like here on stackexchange @gavenkoa would refer to your account. That helps the machine understand that the specific user has been referred to and can act on it (like send you a notification).

# refers to topics. If I write #gavenkoa, the machine (in this case google or any script that identifies hashtags) would classify the text along with *#gavenkoa* as a piece of string relating to the topic #gavenkoa. It does not specify that *gavenkoa* is a username.

So to put it in an example,

> @gavenkoa, I hope your answer about #SocialTags and #Hashtags is answered.